# Logging of ATL class objects

Tags: c++, logging, atl

I have a pretty large Dll library, which is developed in C++ using Microsoft Active Template Library (ATL).

I'm trying to gather test data from this library during runtime, so I can build some good unit tests for it later. Since some of the classes are ridiculously big, it would be very tedious work to manually add logging to all the member functions and log the state of all hundreds of member data variables after every member function is run.

Of course, I don't need to log exactly everything. I could just log the state after the most frequent member functions have been run. However, this library needs to be ported to a more modern stack in the future so it would be good to have solid unit tests.

Is there a way to dump whole ATL objects from memory to file, which can later be easily analyzed? Are there any tools or libraries available for this kind of task?
Can I even find ATL classes that could help me with this?

Comment: ATL only has trace facilities (most are not automatic, need to be declared). There are also some debugging and error reporting facilities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/debugging-and-error-reporting-macros?view=vs-2019 that you can use (an maybe modify to get something). That's it. Otherwise, what you could do is use a C++ parser to instrument the code. If by ATL objects you mean COM objects, it could be useful since there's a pattern that ATL COM objects follow. Another solution is to modify ATL source code itself since it's open source

Comment: ATL itself does not address the mentioned challenges. All standard trick applies: you can produce runtime debug output (with or without `ATLTRACE`), you can create minidumps with Windows Debug Helper API. ATL classes and COM development overall do not offer you any extras here.